# Cyclotomic Numbers, Difference Sets

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I have reading papers by Cunsheng Ding on Binary Cyclotomic Generators, Linear Complexity of Generalised Binary Sequences of Order 2. Since the topic is new to me understanding the text is quite difficult for me, can someone suggest some references and text, I had looked up the references given in the paper but still no clue how to go through it sequentially. I have to submit my report for the project by summarizing these papers. any lead related to it will be very helpful.

Comment: The natural place to go for help is the person to whom you have to submit your report.

Answer (score 1):

A few references:

Rudolf Lidl, Harald Niederreiter
*Finite Fields*
Cambridge University Press, 1997

has a chapter on linear recurring sequences.

*Introduction to Finite Fields and Their Applications*

by the same authors is more approachable, the first being a research monograph.

There is also

*Cryptographic Boolean Functions and Applications* by
Thomas Cusick and Pantelimon Stanica

specifically chapter 7.

Comment: I read the book by Rudolf Lidl, but didn't know much about the Cryptographic Functions, Thank you for suggesting the other book.

Comment: there is also a book on stream ciphers by Ding and Cusick, North Holland.

Comment: Cunsheng Ding-Linear Complexity of Generalised Cyclotomic Binary Sequences of Order 2 and Cyclic Codes From the Two Prime Sequences, for these papers too can you suggest something?

Comment: Well, there is this paper:  https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jmath/2020/6625652/ Its presentation seems nice. Disclaimer, I have not spent any substantial time trying to understand in a deep technical way this paper or for that matter Ding's papers. The rest is up to you.